# How to manipulate colors in QML

Tags: qt, colors, qml, rgba

I would like to do something like this:

```
Item {

    property color primary_color

    Rectangle {
        color: Qt.rgba(primary_color.red/2, primary_color.green, primary_color.blue, primary_color.alpha<0.5?0.25:0.75)
    }
}
```

but how can I acces the properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-color.html documentation:

> A color type has r, g, b and a properties that refer to the red,
>   green, blue and alpha values of the color, respectively. Additionally
>   it has hsvHue, hsvSaturation, hsvValue and hslHue, hslSaturation,
>   hslLightness properties, which allow access to color values in HSV and
>   HSL color models accordingly:

```
Item {

    property color primary_color

    Rectangle {
        color: Qt.rgba(primary_color.r/2, primary_color.g, primary_color.b, primary_color.a<0.5?0.25:0.75)
    }
}
```